# Monitor Google Cloud Messaging Service

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering if there is a way to monitor the service that google provides (**GCM Google Cloud Messaging**), like *listing the registered topics*, *number of registered client* and so on...

I suspect **Google Developers Console** have some functionality for it, but I couldn't find my way in it, Hope someone can point me to it.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that time Google has provided developers with advanced monitoring tool.
The Gcm Diagnostic Tool is available in Google Play developer console. 
So you can easily track the particular message status via registration token.

> Using GCM Diagnostics, you can troubleshoot messages sent through GCM. You can look up the message(s) by Registration token or Message ID.

Here's how to get to your GCM Diagnostics page:

> 1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Select an app that uses GCM.
> 3. On the left menu, click GCM Diagnostics.

Here's how you can look up messages sent through Google Cloud Messaging:

**Registration token**: The GCM identity of the client app on the device. You can find it when your client app registers with GCM. This is also the identity that you'll use to send a GCM message to a device. You should only look up one Registration token at a time.

**Message ID**: The unique GCM message identifier. You can find it in the response message that GCM sends to the client server when GCM confirms that it has received the message. You can look up multiple Message IDs at a time, but they should all be related to the same Registration token. To learn about the different message statuses, refer to the GCM message status section.

See docs here : 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this still true? I can't find GCM Diagnostics and I can only link with an FCM API key from the Play Console (the new GCM).. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TimBaas I am also looking for GCM Diagnostics for it seems like they completely removed it and replaced it for FCM. I tried entering my GCM data but it didn't allow it...

Comment: Is this supposed to work for FCM topic messages? I'm trying to get diagnostics using Message IDs but the page says "Please enter a valid Registration token or Message ID(s)."

Comment: from https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en: November 30, 2017: FCM diagnostics data removed
You can no longer access FCM diagnostics data in the Play Console.
You can still use other Firebase Cloud Messaging features.